# Animation error in gdm3 Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: themes, ubuntu-gnome, gdm

I tried searching a lot for the above error but didn't find any solution to this,

I installed flat-remix-themes
https://github.com/daniruiz/flat-remix-gnome and on rebooting this screen appears.

I tried reinstalling **gdm3** and uninstalled flat-remix-gnome but the problem still remains,

here are few snapshots

Before Clicking on User
[image: before clicking on user]

and this on Clicking on User
[image: on clicking on user]

Comment: So remove "flat-remix-themes"

Comment: @astrophilic Hi, how did you reinstall gdm3? can you specify the steps you did?

Comment: This worked for me

**sudo apt remove flat-remix-gnome
sudo apt install --reinstall ubuntu-gnome-desktop gdm3
sudo update-alternatives --auto gdm3.css**

Comment: so the problem solved now.. thats nice.. you can write your own answer and accept it after 2days..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were two DMs one above the other that caused the issue.

I selected an alternative theme using `gnome-tweak-tool`

and then removed the theme.
`sudo apt remove flat-remix-gnome`

And reinstalled default gnome-desktop gdm3 using
`sudo apt install --reinstall ubuntu-gnome-desktop gdm3`

and restarted gdm3 service
`sudo systemctl restart gdm3`